# div slider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am creating a div slider with the help of few posts here in StackOverflow but it is not working for some reason. Shows there is some error on the Jquery, which i don't see. I need a second set of eyes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Previous Next</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 .table-container {
    width:456px; /* Total width of visible columns + border widths */
    height:300px;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    background-color:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sliding-window {
    width:760px; /* Total width of all columns in sliding-window + border widths */
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sliding-window div {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#aaa;
    border:solid 1px #999;
}
​
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#next-column').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'+=152'}, 'slow');        
    });

    $('#previous-column').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'-=152'}, 'slow');        
    });

});​
</script>

</head>

<body>

<a id="previous-column" href="#">Previous</a>
<a id="next-column" href="#">Next</a>
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="sliding-window">
        <div id="col-1">
            <p>This is the content of the first column in the sliding table</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-2">
            <p>This is the content of the second column in the sliding table</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-3">
            <p>This is the content of the third column in the sliding table</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-4">
            <p>This is the content of the fourth column in the sliding table</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col-5">
            <p>This is the content of the fifth column in the sliding table</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
​
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ldaniell14260/Wymfr/ I just copied your code and it works

Comment: invalid character line 45 ..I don't see what is invalid on line 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to get this working.

Be sure your script is being pulled into the page, one way to check is by using the 'sources' tab in the Chrome Debugger and searching for the file else in the html head section

Be sure that you've included the datatale script after you've included jQuery, as it is most certainly dependant upon that.

Check whether jQuery is included properly and once only.

Watch out for jQuery conflicts. There is some other library which is overridding $, so your code is not working because $ is not an alias for jQuery anymore. You can use jQuery.noConflict() to avoid conflicts with other libraries on the page which use the same variable $.